configure Splunk logging in log4j based on environment in mule 4
my requirement is to configure 2 Splunk configuration in log4j based on the environment.
Basically the Splunk server/url will be different for production and lower environment.
How i can configure dynamically this in my log4j. Is there any portal or explanation that i can refer?

You can define a System Property and reference it from the log4j2.xml file using the syntax ${sys:PROPERTYNAME}.
Example:
<AsyncLogger name="${sys:log.name}" level="${sys:log.level}"/>

You can define a system property in different ways:

Runtime Manager: Application / Settings / Properties
On prem deployments: in the MULE_HOME/conf/wrapper.conf file adding a line like wrapper.java.additional.123=-Dlog.name=myfile.log
Studio: Run As / Run Configurations / Arguments tab / VM Arguments with syntax -Dlog.name=myfile.log

Properties file inside the application won't work because those properties are not system properties.
References

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/latest/mule-app-properties-system
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=001114527&type=1

